How to enter in Unicode a greek letter with hat?
In this Emacs.SE question, I see that one can enter Unicode characters for English letters with a hat.
For example, in Emacs 29 under Ubuntu 24.04,
C-x 8 ^ a  gives â
Is there a way to enter a Unicode character with a Greek letter (e.g. φ or \phi ) under the hat?
In general, is there a way to enter other modified versions of characters such as \mathcal{A}?

Perhaps you can use the MS Word shortcut, CtrlShift^ to add the diacritic to Alt237. You might also try changing the keyboard layout to add dead-key composition of characters.
One issue is that, though there are some Greek characters that traditionally may be written with diacritics, accented φ is not one.There are lists, such as at Keynote Support, that show the key press combinations for standard accented characters, such as the following, (tested in LibreOffice Writer):

Alt912 for ΐ, iota with dialitika and tonos, or
Alt942 for ή, eta with tonos.

Another issue is that other diacritics may be composed, but accent circumflex is not.
A third issue is that the two Greek marks for accent circumflex are notthat used in the Latin alphabet: ῟, ἇ, ἧ, and ᾧ, and ῁, ῗ, and ῧ.

"Hat" == Circumflex. Characters (Ubuntu) or Character Map (Windows) allows to search for circumflex - to show e.g. Combining circumflex ... (U+0302) and "ready made" characters with circumflex. How to use "Combining" versions left to be investigated, here.

Ubuntu Terminal: <CTRL+SHIFT+U> 0302  z  =>  ̂z  (not shown combined here)
